# foregroundService in android java

Tags: java, android

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        startForegroundService(new Intent(this,service.class));
    }
```

Here's the source code. As we can see, startForegroundService works above 25 API level. But, my question is how **Facebook**, **Instagram** and **WhatsApp** use it in every API level?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using androidx (which IMO you should be), you can use [`ContextCompat.startForegroundServce`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/ContextCompat#startForegroundService(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) which works on all API versions

If not, you can check the API version before you call:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    context.startForegroundService(intent);
} else {
    context.startService(intent);
}
```

Note that [`Service.startForeground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) is available since API 5, which means your service can be foreground without calling `startForegroundService` on those API versions.

If you are curious why that changed in API 26, here is a quote from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services):

> Prior to Android 8.0, the usual way to create a foreground service was to create a background service, then promote that service to the foreground. With Android 8.0, there is a complication; the system doesn't allow a background app to create a background service. For this reason, Android 8.0 introduces the new method [`startForegroundService()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)) to start a new service in the foreground. After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) method to show the new service's user-visible notification. If the app does *not* call [`startForeground()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)) within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be [ANR](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr).